# Утилита конвертации dwg в картинку

Tags: поиск-программ, autocad

Нужна утилитка командной строки для конвертации файлов AutoCAD (dwg, dxf) в png (или bmp). Целевая ОС: Windows.
Подскажите, может знает кто нибудь такую? А то что то не получается найти в интернете

Comment: Утилитами - искать dwg2bmp первая же ссылка поиска http://qcad.org/en/products/qcad-command-line-tools На счёт бесплатной - не могу сказать... Поробуйте по запросу dwg2bmp перебирать ссылки.

Comment: Другой вариант - найти dwg rendering для вашего языка высокого уровня (с#, c++, java и т п), отрендерить и сохранить в тот же bmp.